# Vulnerability found in my project, but not in library itself

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I use the library `tokio-postgres-rustls` in one of my projects.

The project is being scanned against vulnerabilites within the GitHub Actions. I receive the following error:

[image: RUSTSEC-2020-0071]

So looking at this, I thought the library `tokio-postgres-rustls` has a problem since it uses `time 0.1.44` as a transitive dependency, which itself is apparently not safe.

Then I did the very same scan directly on the `tokio-postgres-rustls` library: [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/gcomte/tokio-postgres-rustls/runs/4816732673)

Surprisingly though, it did *not* detect any problems on that library!

So I was wondering ... what is the discrepancy between my own project that uses the library `tokio-postgres-rustls` and the library `tokio-postgres-rustls` itself? How do their transitive dependencies differ?

Comment: Maybe this a question for the companies, software, libraries and authors involved?

Comment: Your smoking gun is https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/blob/main/Cargo.toml#L39 -- `chrono` really does pull in the vulnerable `time` release. `postgres-types` is optionally pulled in with time 0.2 or 0.3, controlled by features plumbed through https://github.com/sfackler/rust-postgres/blob/master/postgres-types/Cargo.toml. `chrono` is listed as optional, which might have something to do with why it's not always a problem.

Comment: Anyhow -- if chrono can be updated to support a newer version of `time`, that's certainly worth doing. But what dependencies the library has itself are very prone to configuration; it smells to me like the GH action scan doesn't walk all possible dependency trees with different feature configurations.

Comment: Taking a quick look at the audit, it appears to be auditing `Cargo.lock`, so it's only running down a specific configuration's dependencies; other configurations are out-of-scope for the scan.

Comment: That is a [known concern at chrono](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono/issues/602). Updating `time` isn't enough to fix all known problems though: [RUSTSEC-2020-0159](https://rustsec.org/advisories/RUSTSEC-2020-0159.html)